# How to create a single volley webservice class to use across the android app?

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-volley

My android application uses multiple network calls in a single activity and i have several of these activities where i have to use both post and get requests. I want to create a single "VolleyWebservice" class and call the same in multiple activities instead of writing the complete volley code. I am relatively new to android development and i don't understand where i am going wrong.

```
public class VolleyWebService {

public JSONObject result;

public JSONObject getResponse(String url, Context mContext) {
    RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Anshuman" + response.toString());

            result =  response;
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    mQueue.add(request);
   return result;
}
}
```

The method in My activity where i am calling this class

```
    private void callFunctionGetDist() {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(recorddata.this, "", "Please Wait...", true);
    JSONObject response = new VolleyWebService().getResponse(urlConfigClass.GET_DISTRICT, this);
    try {
        if(response.toString().contains("Status:Success,Details")){
            arrDistName.clear();
            arrDistCode.clear();
            arrDistName.add("Select District Name");
            arrDistCode.add("Select District Code");
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Status:Success,Details");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jobJ = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String scheName = jobJ.getString("post");
                JSONObject jobJDist = new JSONObject(scheName);
                String distname = jobJDist.getString("District");
                String distcode = jobJDist.getString("DistrictCode");
                arrDistName.add(distname);
                arrDistCode.add(distcode);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(recorddata.this,
                    R.layout.custom_textview_to_spinner, arrDistName);
            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            district.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }else{
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response is null or empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception volleyError) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I tried creating the same class but i am not able to get the response to other activities. Although i am getting the correct response in the Volley jsonbject response, the response return null in other activities.

I want to have the result object return the response in my recorddata activity

This is what i have tried so far, no luck though!

```
  public void postResponse (String url, Context mContext, final VolleyResponseListener listener) {
    try {
        String encodedUrl = url.replace(" ", "%20") + "";
        if (encodedUrl.contains("("))
            encodedUrl = encodedUrl.replace("(", "%28");
        if (encodedUrl.contains(")"))
            encodedUrl = encodedUrl.replace(")", "%29");
        encodedUrl = encodedUrl.replace(" ", "%20");

        RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POst, encodedUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Anshuman" + response.toString());

                listener.onSuccess(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        listener.onError(error);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                return new HashMap<>();
            }

        };

        mQueue.add(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? Please post your code, so we can help you iterate it and identify your problem specifically.

Comment: Hey, just posted the my Volley class code. Please have a look. i want the "result" jsonobject to return the volley response in another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of achieving your goal, (without taking in to consideration architecture and coding principles), you can pass a callback:

```
public class VolleyWebService {

public interface VolleyResponseListener {
  void onSuccess(JSONObject response);
  void onError(VolleyError error);
}

public JSONObject result;

public JSONObject getResponse(String url, Context mContext, VolleyResponseListener listener) {
    RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Anshuman" + response.toString());

            listener.onSuccess(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   listener.onError(error);
                }
            });

    mQueue.add(request);
   return result;
}
}
```

To use it:

```
volleyWebService.getResponse("your url", context, new VolleyResponseListener() {
   @Override
   void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
      //do what you want on success
   }

   @Override
   void onError(VolleyError error) {
      //do what you want on error
   }
});
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how can i do the same for post requests ?

Comment: you can make it as a parameter, or create another method for it. Try to play with it.

Comment: Please have a look at my original post.  I have posted my postresponse class.